# Output remote hostname in sshpass session

Tags: shell, sed, replace, hostname, sshpass

I have created a shell script to connect to a list of servers using sshpass and run a list of about 30 commands. An extract of the script is below.

The script will wget a new config file, but then I am stuck trying to replace a variable in the config file with the server hostname.

I've had no luck getting the remote server hostname, only the local hostname (in this case MacBookPro!) will output.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read PASSWORD SERVER
do
  sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" ssh -t -p 1234 $SERVER << !
   echo "Server: $SERVER"
   wget -N https://example.com/file.conf 2>&1 | grep -i "failed\|error\|saved"
```

attempt 1:

```
   replace "variabletoreplace" "$HOSTNAME" -- file.conf
```

attempt 2:

```
   sed -i "s/variabletoreplace/$(<file.conf)/"  /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
```

end of the script:

```
!
done <./server_list.txt
```

I've also attempted assigning variables like host=$(hostname -f) or $HOST, but nothing will display the remote host.

I understand in normal ssh commands this type of issue can be down to use of double-quotes instead of single-quotes, but I'm not sure how to amend the script I have whilst keeping it as a list of commands. Any help appreciated.

Comment: you'd save yourself a lot of effort here and be more secure, too, by using ssh keys to authenticate.  Also, this is what `ansible` is for and you might find that would be a faster way to success than writing your own similar thing, though I'm not sure ansible supports multiple passwords per host.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` before the `$HOSTNAME` variable (or `$(hostname)` command), so that it is expanded/run on the remote machine rather than the local machine:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read PASSWORD SERVER;do
  sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" ssh -t -p 1234 $SERVER << EOF
    wget -N https://example.com/file.conf 2>&1 | grep -i "failed\|error\|saved"
    sed -i "s/variabletoreplace/\$HOSTNAME/" file.conf
  EOF
done
```

As mentioned in comments it would be much better to use ssh keys rather than `sshpass` and if all these commands you want to run were in a script on the remote host it would be a lot simpler. Alternatively using a tool like `ansible` or `puppet` may be more appropriate.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me. Even when I run the command from a direct SSH session:
`sed -i "s/variabletoreplace/\$HOSTNAME/" file.conf`

It's actually putting $HOSTNAME into file.conf

The example I gave in my initial post did work with direct SSH connection:

`sed -i "s/variabletoreplace/$(<file.conf)/"  /proc/sys/kernel/hostname`

...but then it didn't work over sshpass.

Unless you have any other ideas, I agree that putting the command into a script on the remote host is probably the way forward.

Comment: You wouldn't escape the `$` if you're running in locally.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have repeated my earlier testing and your solution is working now. Thanks very much.

Comment: Glad to help, please accept the answer if it's working for you.